# First-time JQuery hover effect jumps to endpoint, normal thereafter

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, rollover-effect

Here's a poser:

Load the page, on first time mouseover hover of the Mail and LinkedIn Tabs, the animation jumps to the endpoint frame.  It should animate the tab drop.

After the first hover, everything is OK, hover behaves as expected.  Tried mouseenter, mouseover and hover.  Personally, I like mouseenter best but that's me.  The behavior is similar to the horizontal topics buttons below, which don't exhibit the jump.  Weird.

Code looks like this:

```
$("#zipperTabLinkedin a")
    .mouseenter(function(e){
        $(this).animate(
            {padding:'30px 0 0 0'},
            {duration:500},
            {easing:'swing'})
    })
    .mouseleave(function(e){
        $(this).animate(
        {padding:'5px 0 0 0'},
        {duration:500},
        {easing:'swing'})
});
```

Just weird.  You can see the effect at:  http://desertbiz.biz/repl.html

Comment: Try animating `paddingTop` with simple values of "30px" and "5px" instead of using the `padding` shortcut property.

Comment: [here's a localized test case, looks fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Mwja/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/7Mwja/3/. There was a `:hover` selector as well.

Comment: @Blender well played sir, very well played. There's the answer.

Comment: try css3 transitions for padding prorperty.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `padding-top` in the `a:hover`.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Mwja/6/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with css3 transitions which never fails.

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Mwja/5/)

use the transion property to animate it.

```
 -webkit-transition:padding-top 0.1s ease-in;
```

Tutorial for css3 transitions

www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

(only drawback is you should write cross browser css)